# Angular 10 application deployment on GCP Kubernetes istio ingress cluster

Tags: angular, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio

I am trying to deploy an angular 8/9/10 app on GCP cluster; with Istio.
I am getting the following issue

1. All loading js files are giving error of 404
2. The same application working fine with LoadBalancer and not by Ingress

Can anyone help me with an example of angular + gcp kubernetes istio ingress as load balancer.

Comment: Please provide more information. Its GCP VMs as Kubeadm or its GKE cluster? How did you deployed Ingress? Provide your configuration and exact error.

Comment: 404 is a path issue probably (it can't find). Is it a GCP cluster (Compute Engine VMs) or GKE cluster? I edited your question, and changed it to GKE, but now I doubt.